# One big sign up button or 3

Tags: usability, website-design, buttons

I would like to know what is the best use in web homepage are for Sign up button:

1. One big button (Like example 1) and then to open screen with option to sign up with facebook, google or mail[image]
2. or 3 buttons like example 2 
   [image]

Comment: Traffic-permitting, you might want to actually A/B test both options. When I worked on A/B testing at Stack Exchange, the "all buttons" option won on one page (the anonymous comment and vote popups), whereas the "one button" won on another page (the tour page). I'd argue this demonstrates there is no one "true" answer.

Comment: This is one of those things that likely heavily depends on implementation and the overall visual design. Context is also key here as well in understanding *what* I am about to sign up for.

Answer (score 42):

A Facebook or Google+ sign-in method can actually encourage people to sign-up at all. Most users value the uncomplicated experience they get when signing up via Google+ or Facebook. Hiding this option behind another click will make this valuable option invisible and prevent sign-ups by "lazy" users.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that OAuth can encourage people to sign up. Personally, I love it when a company allows me to sign up using either Google, Facebook or Twitter, because it makes the registration process so much easier, faster and safer. It also means I don't have yet ANOTHER password to store in my password vault, and that in the case of a company breach, I'm not as affected since they don't store my password.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs thats my personal experience too. OAuth Sign-Ups allow me to manage all access tokens in a central place and keep an eye on them.

Comment: Keep in mind though that the typical user of ux.stackexchange is probably more aware of these issues and thus more interested in OAuth-style signups than the typical user of some other less technical website. You're not an unbiased sample.

Comment: I'm not sure this fully answers the question of 1 button vs 3.

Answer (score 9):

According to Hick's Law, the more options a user is faced with; the harder it will be for them to make a decision quickly.

For this reason, I would suggest the single button as on the homepage,as at this stage the user is making the decision of **what** they want to do.  If they decide they want to sign up, the user can then be faced with the sign up options on the second step.

That being said, things like this are always worth A/B testing!

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hick%27s_law

Comment: Another idea might be to have the one button in a bar somewhere, then get directed to the sign-up page with all the different options.

Answer (score 4):

I actually like the second option of showing Google, FB sign in options directly. Nowadays most users have such accounts and knowing that 'getting - in' process is just one click away encourages users to click on one of those options. With first option, you might lose some users right at the gate.

I think Hicks law (as pointed out by Thomad Adcock) is not valid here, because of the limited , well established (standard user authentication on web, these days) sign-in options that are made available. Hicks law makes a valid case if there are too many choices available that user has to 'weigh' in before making a decision. Here I am hardly wasting any time choosing between FB or Google. My two cents.

Comment: ... And in general, people will have one or the other that they *usually* use to sign in.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the variant which already shows all the options separate, like it's done on Stack Exchange:

> [image]

While the second one immediately shows the visitor how they can sign up, the first one just appears to make an excess step, there's no need in those forewords, considering you're going to implement all those different sign up ways.

I'd even say that making the large button with the text like this will discourage to proceed at least me, because this text gives it a look of the typical adverts.

---

A note (inspired by Stack Exchange design a bit): if you have anything that doesn't require logging in and allows anonymous browsing, you should probably present it before the log in screen or combine them, otherwise it'd look like you're probably obtruding the signup upon the potential users.

E.g, taking into account the links seen in the navigation bar on the image you've provided, you could present

```
Visit our blog | explore our jobs

{ some recent  | { top jobs }
 entries }     |

 -------------------------------

 { greetingz, advantages of 
      signing up briefly }

 log in |sign up|
 ------           ---------------

 Signup using following services:
 { Google }     |    { Facebook }
           { options }
      Or create a {your-brand}
           account below:
             [email]
             [pswd ]
            [confirm]

           { sign up }
```

(It was actually supposed to be *just* a not, since I'm not a designer)

Comment: It should be noted that as a new, accountless user, you have to click "Join this community" to get to that page.

Comment: @cat No, it happens if you already have another account im the network logged in :) otherwise you're presented with "sign up | log in" in the top bar, but as it's being only a bar, there's no place for the form in it.

Comment: Much after the answer, but it should be borne in mind that SE is users who are relative more savvy than those of the average app. So the design choices should reflect that as well.